# Compatibility issue when converting an XUnit project to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have XUnit projects that I want to use in VS2017.

I loaded the solution with these projects in VS2017 and it converted from Project.json to csproj but I am unable to run my tests without error:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"}
```

**UPDATE:**
I found that adding System.Net.Http to the test project resolved this.. Why in the world would I have to do this? My test project is calling a DLL that uses System.Net.Http, but why would the test project need it?